# How can I rotate boxes around an offset center?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I try to reproduce this animation of [horikawa.j](https://www.instagram.com/horikawa.j/) with *Geometry Nodes*, which I discovered on Instagram.

[image]

The original creator says that this was solved with `Transfer Attributes`.

[Source: Rotating boxes with Geometry Nodes](https://www.instagram.com/p/CYW5ZpghRPU/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't understand from where which attribute should be transferred here, but if you're interested in another solution as well, this *100% procedural* example might help you:

[image]

1. Here I first create a cube, whose sides I extrude and then combine with the node `Mesh Boolean` and scaled version of the cube so that I am left with a wire mesh.
2. I instantiate this mesh at a single point offset by the size of the cube. The reason I do this is because I can easily rotate the instance around a given point afterwards.
3. Then I feed the current frame into the node `Map Range` which returns a rotation between $0°$ and $180°$ (in radians!). You can alternatively solve this using the node `Float Curve`. This value then controls the rotation of the cube.
4. Finally, I flip the cube, and rotate the resulting objects twice by $90°$ in different directions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for ! Your process is very efficient to make loops